# how to get 'this' element by id and see if checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a list of checkboxes and I'd like to know if 'this' checkbox is checked. So I though this simple bit of code would work but I got an error of: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`.

The code I used was simply `document.getElementById(this).checked;`. I thought this would work honestly, but apparently not. I assume the problem is that the function `getElementById` is expecting an `id`. How would I get the element of 'this'?

Comment: as the name suggest document.getElementById expects ID of element not 'this' …!

Comment: this is referring to object...you need to pass id value to getElementById

Comment: What do you mean by "element of this" ? why can't you just use $(this) ?

Comment: `this` refers to your actual element, so it would be `this.checked`, you don't need to get it by an id. Of course not it depends on the scope, we may need to see more of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `this` is referring to the dom element then you could simply use

```
this.checked
```